# Merge two Mongo cluster

Tags: mongodb

I have currently two Mongo clusters running that I would like to merge. One option would be to use mongodump/mongoimport to copy the data from one cluster to another. My question is if this would also be possible on file system level (copy the data files from one cluster to another) since this would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MMAP, and none of the data files or databases have the same name on both servers, then you might be able to copy the files together.  Otherwise, no, combining the files from 2 servers would not merge the data sets.

Since MMAP is deprecated in MongoDB 4.0 and not supported in 4.2, the odds are not very good.  Mongodump/mongorestore is probably your best option.

Comment: Thanks. No I am using wired tiger so I have to go with mongo-dump